# Rigging and auto weight painting not working

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify

I have no doubles, my normals are outward, rig is lined up, but the rig isn't actually deforming the model at all and auto weight painting isn't doing anything.

Can someone take a look at my file and tell me what I need to fix? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w2nGJB_rLT6Ca2_q-DRxv-BcD1DFXZae/view?usp=sharing

I'm incredibly frustrated with this right now and don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at your character.

It appears you've parented the metarig to your character which creates an infinitate loop. blender stops that from happening to avoid crashes. The solution is very simple:

Unparent your character mesh and try again. Here are some pictures to help you.

[image]

Loop in Parents is the error you get. Looking at your outliner, you can see the metarig is a child of the character mesh. Click and drag it un clear the rig of its parent.

Again, selecting the character mesh first and then the rig second in object mode. Press Ctrl+P and parent with automatic weights.

Now the rig works perfectly. Easy mistake to make, easy solution to fix it.

I would also note that the hierarchy is a bit strange. I would parent the thigh bones to the pelvis .L and .R NOT the spine bone but it depends what you want.

Here is your edited file in case you need to compare.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzliftzf727jzpa/SpidSunSh_edit.blend?dl=0

I hope that helps.

Comment: In terms of the thigh bones, I didn't change anything about the parenting of the bones. I just used the rig creation thing from rigify. Not sure what happened there.

Comment: Also, once I did it, I got some weird clipping in the wrist. Found that the normals were reversed and fixed that, but I still have that clipping

Comment: Btw, about the name, it was originally going to be a model of Gwen but then i decided to make it my friends character and never renamed it so I should def do that. 

The clipping was extra faces got made somewhere along the way and the normals for said faces were reversed.

Comment: Yea, I guess this is one of your first models right? Making mistakes is all part of the process of learning. All part of the fun. Looking good though for a first model!

Comment: It's not my first model, as I've animated before, but it's my second human/humanoid model.

Comment: Also, how would I make the hat move with the head? Joining the two objects doesn's seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Now your mesh is the parent of your rig, so can't be the rig the parent of the mesh.

Find the armature object's parent and remove it (click on the X next to it)
[image]